# Google Adwords Conversion Code Integration To A CMS Page in Prestashop?

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop, google-ads-api, prestashop-1.6

I've read countless advices how to insert GA Conversion code to order-`confirmation.tpl`. (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194608/add-google-adwords-conversion-tracking-javascript-code-into-a-prestashop-sma)), but what if i need it inserted in my "Contact Us" CMS page?

I cannot simply add it via editor (receive a "Content Field is invalid" error). I cannot do it via FTP because these cms pages are generated on the fly, right? So is there a way to pull this through?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify via FTP `themes/[your-theme]/cms.tpl` file and insert some code like this (making it loaded only for selected CMS pages).

`{literal}...{/literal}` - prevents from errors in `.tpl` file, but it is reading variables literally. So if you need to add some `smarty` variables to `javascript` there, you can remove `{literal}...{/literal}` if it is safe or close and open `{literal}` again around the `smarty` variable.

`YOUR_ID`, `ANOTHER_ID` - IDs of CMS pages, integers.

```
{if isset($cms) && ($cms->id == YOUR_ID || $cms->id == ANOTHER_ID)}

    {literal}

    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */

        {* Google Addwords code ... *}
        var google_conversion_value = {/literal}{$total}{literal};    

    /* ]]> */
    </script>

    {/literal}

{/if}
```

Comment: Dekui! Judging by the source code it got added. Made my day!